# Mongodb query find if documents exist in the DB

Tags: mongodb

I've been trying to do something I don't know if I can in MongoDB (or any other DB), but what I want is to do a `find` type of query where the return is individual to each of the attributes. It's like a "Find which ones exist".

For example, I'd like to send something like:

```
db.getCollection('products').find({'id': {$or: [1,2,3,4,5] } })
```

And I'd like the answer to be something like:

```
{
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: false,
  4: false,
  5: true
}
```

Is there a way to do so? I'm thinking not, but I'd like to know if there is anything I can do to make it work to avoid extra processing on my server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your search array into a single field and `$unwind` them to make them independent documents. Then, perform self `$lookup` to check for existence.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$limit": 1
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ids: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$ids"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "ids",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "selfLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      records: {
        $push: {
          id: "$ids",
          exists: {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $ne: [
                  [],
                  "$selfLookup"
                ]
              },
              "then": true,
              "else": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uxWbq5ENqNm)

Comment: Thank you so much. Thats exactly what I was looking for.